# C++ при записи структуры в файл с помощью fwrite в файле отображаются крякозябры

Tags: c++

Делаю лабу в универе. Есть структуры, данные которых вводятся с клавиатуры, потом записываются в файл с помощью функции `fwrite()`. До сих пор работал только с `fstream`, и проблем не возникало. Тут тоже вроде как всё сделал правильно, но на выхлопе получаю файл `device.txt`, а в нём сплошные крякозябры. Собираю с под линукса g++. 
Вся программа на гите https://github.com/rotenbergwitalik/laba6.git

код с main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

#define DEVICE_NAME_LEN     30
#define MEASUREVALUE_NAME_LEN     30

using namespace std;

struct powerSource {
    float voltage;
    float amperage;
    float periodicity;
};

struct measuredValue {
    char measuredValueName[MEASUREVALUE_NAME_LEN];
    float lowBorder;
    float highBorder;
    float inaccuracy;
};

struct device {
    char deviceName[DEVICE_NAME_LEN];//
    float devicePrice;
    int guarantee; //in month
    struct powerSource devicePowerSource;
    struct measuredValue deviceMeasureValue;
};
int main() {
    struct device labaDevice;

    cout<<"Write name of device: ";
    cin>>labaDevice.deviceName;
    cout<<"Write price of device in $: ";
    cin>>labaDevice.devicePrice;
    cout<<"Write guarantee in month: ";
    cin>>labaDevice.guarantee;

    cout<<"Write power source for device: "<<endl;
    cout<<"\tVoltage: ";
    cin>>labaDevice.devicePowerSource.voltage;
    cout<<"\tAmperage: ";
    cin>>labaDevice.devicePowerSource.amperage;
    cout<<"\tPeriodicity: ";
    cin>>labaDevice.devicePowerSource.periodicity;

    cout<<"Write measure value for device: "<<endl;
    cout<<"Write name of measure value: ";
    cin>>labaDevice.deviceMeasureValue.measuredValueName;
    cout<<"\tLow border: ";
    cin>>labaDevice.deviceMeasureValue.lowBorder;
    cout<<"\tHigh border: ";
    cin>>labaDevice.deviceMeasureValue.highBorder;
    cout<<"\tInaccuracy: ";
    cin>>labaDevice.deviceMeasureValue.inaccuracy;

    FILE* outFile;
    if ((outFile = fopen("device.txt", "wb")) == NULL) {
        cout<<"Con not open the file"<<endl;
        return 1;
    }

    fwrite(&labaDevice, sizeof(device), 1, outFile);

    fclose(outFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что вы просто раньше выводили поля с помощью оператора вывода в поток `<<`, т.е. в текстовом виде. `fwrite` пишет данные в бинарном виде, как есть. Режим `wt` меняет одно - обработку `\n`. Если вы хотите получать все данные в текстовом виде, используйте `fprintf` - типа, вместо

```
outStream << "guarantee = " << labaDevice.guarantee << endl;
```

используйте

```
fprintf(outFile,"guarantee = %d\n",labaDevice.guarantee);
```

Но учтите, что если потом надо будет считывать - то считывать тоже надо будет текстово. А если используете `fwrite` в бинарном режиме - то потом всю структуру сразу втянете одним `fread` в том же бинарном режиме...

Comment: а если не затруднит, можно кусок кода как правильно применить в моем случае fread() и fwrite(). Или хотя бы ссылочку на хороший мануал, дабы разобраться. А то не очень понятно, про бинарный режим.

Comment: @V.Rotenberh Да просто fwrite - запись всего, что сказали так, как оно лежит в памяти. Числа - в их бинарном представлении и т.д. А считываете точно так же - только функцией fread, в подготовленное место (такую же структуру). Только файл должен обязательно быть открыт в бинарном режиме (c "b" в строке режима открытия) - чтобы как в памяти лежит, так и в файл шло.

Comment: тоисть при записи с помощью данных функций в любом случае, увидеть текст в файле в нормальном представлении не получится?

Comment: @V.Rotenberh только при записи обычных строк с текстом.

Comment: спасибо, кажись понял.

Answer (score 1):

"Кракозябры" зависят от того просмотрщика, которым ты этот файл смотришь.
Большинство из них пытаются определить кодировку автоматом.
Но т. к. файл записывается не текстовый а бинарный, то вполне возможны ошибки.
Если под linux, то из консоли можно посмотреть тем же mc F3. После открытия Alt+E и выбираешь ту, которая у тебя стоит - utf-8, например.
Да, и лучше переключится в HEX - режим, чтобы просмотрщик не пытался интерпретировать значения из float или int как текст. :)

Кстати, имей в виду, что если кодировка у тебя utf-8 и ты используешь не ascii символы, например русские, то длинна строки в байтах может увеличится раза в 3.
Так что при вводе имени из 10-15 символов можешь затереть остальные поля структуры мусором или схватить переполнение стека. :)

Comment: Да проблема проста, как швабра: бинарные данные, числа, записываются как бинарные данные. Какие еще utf-8? При чем тут они?...

Comment: Автор пишет: "но на выхлопе получаю файл device.txt, а в нём сплошные крякозябры."
Стало быть он открывает его каким-то текстовым просмотрщиком или редактором (расширение файла *.txt), который и показывает "крякозябры". Что вполне естественно, т. к. файл не текстовый а бинарный.
Насчёт utf-8 - смотрим структуры и видим поля с типом `char [...NAME_LEN]`. Судя по вопросам автор не очень силён в кодировках, поэтому я и предупредил его, где могут быть проблемы с переполнением, если используется utf-8, ведь в коде никакой проверки нет.

Comment: Он перед этим тем же просмотрщиком открывал точно такой же файл...

Comment: Этого в вопросе нет. А по фразе "До сих пор работал только с fstream, и проблем не возникало." можно только гадать что это была за "работа". :)

Comment: в кодировках таки не силен. Открывал всем, до чего руки дотянулись. Но спасибо harry разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

Следует исправить строчку (открытие файла в бинарном режиме)

```
if ((outFile = fopen("device.txt", "wb")) == NULL) {
```

на строчку:

```
if ((outFile = fopen("device.txt", "wt")) == NULL) {
```

После этого надо вручную выводить все поля структуры примерно вот так:

```
fwrite("labaDevice.deviceName = ", sizeof("labaDevice.deviceName = "), 1, outFile);
fwrite(labaDevice.deviceName, sizeof(labaDevice.deviceName), 1, outFile);
```

Comment: Ну и что человек получит при выводе `fwrite(labaDevice.guarantee, sizeof(labaDevice.guarantee),1,outFile);`?